# add meta key and meta value to post in wordpress programmatically

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to add custom meta key and meta value in wordpress post from a custom post type? I've tried to research everything in google but still no luck. Do you have any ideas guys? thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible to add custom meta data in WordPress pragmatically using [add_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) function

```
add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);
```

For example if you want to add meta data with key name `age` and value `25` to post with id `10` then you can do it like

```
<?php add_post_meta(10, 'age', 25); ?>
```

In above example, a meta key with `age` and value with `25` will be added to the post id `10` and also you can use it in your template using [get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function like

```
<?php $age = get_post_meta(10, 'age', true); ?>
```

Above line of code will get `age` meta value from post id 10, which is `25`, so you can print it in the template as

```
<?php echo $age; // 25 ?>
```

**Update:**
Just add this in your `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'my_add_custom_fields');
function my_add_custom_fields($post_id)
{
    if ( $_POST['post_type'] == 'your_post_type' ) {
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'my_meta_key_name', 'my meta value', true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: tnx for the respond. but i want to do it in another way. i want all of the post would be added every time the user make a post in admin area.